# How can I configure my AngularJS 5.0.1 application to load my scripts only when the html is loaded?

Tags: angularjs

I'm starting my first AngularJS 5.0.1 application using this theme: https://themeforest.net/item/ubold-responsive-web-app-kit/13489470

But I'm having some problems... The .js files required for the theme that I've put on angular-cli.json are loaded before the HTML, so the script can't find the elements to apply the necessary events to the theme. I need firstly load the HTML, and only after that, load de .js files. Someone could help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

I used to do that on AngularJS by adding a $timeout around ~150ms and then load the functions I need.

Hope it's useful for you.

Comment: But how can I do that if the scripts are automatically loaded from the AngularJS? I mean, I've just added my scripts in my .angular-cli.json and the framework load them automatically.